# home_url(); showing current page instead of site address

Tags: urls, home-url

Does anyone have an idea why my home_url() function gets the URL of the current page instead of the site address? (The site runs locally using MAMP.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't post actual code in your question, I can only speculate. However, a common problem is that, when calling `home_url()`, it is not *echoed*. The [value of the function is *returned*, rather than *echoed*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), so it must be explicitly echoed by the code.

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
<a href="<?php home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
```

Which renders like so:

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

...and would explain why the linked URL is the current page, rather than the expected URL for the site front page.

If so, change it to this:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Chip, I just figured it out and yes you are right. I forgot the damn echo.